# Now that Apple have stopped selling Click Wheel Games is there a repository for them?

Tags: applications, ipod-classic

I'm aware that I'm probably some kind of technological dinosaur but I love my click-wheel iPod. Now that Apple had stopped selling the click wheel games is there somewhere else I can get them?

Is there an equivalent to cydia / or jail-breaking my iPod classic to get home brew or the like games on it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is [the full archive all 54 games on Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/ipod-click-wheel-games-archive). 34 have not been cracked but if you have them on your account you can still use them and if you do let me know ill pay to authorise.

There is a renewed effort to crack them though for those that know arm assembly and may want to help

Answer (score 0):

I tried and failed to find a repository a while back, however if you're lucky, there are torrents for the complete archive which crop up sometimes. Obviously the torrents exist in multiple places, but there are rarely any seeders.

Obviously you'd have had to purchase them to be entitled to use them, and if you had purchased them, you wouldn't have been able to download them again as this was all before you were able to re-download purchased apps, so this may be an ideal solution to get things you'd lost and not backed up.

Answer (score 0):

There's ways and means of getting the iPod games but they're predominately illegal, if it's just those games you want I'd contact Apple as whilst they've probably stopped selling them somewhere they won't have gotten rid of them completely. If it's just a case of extra functionality and games for it I'd highly recommend looking at the Rockbox project which does come with games and is still under active development.

Here's [Rockbox](http://www.rockbox.org) and there's plenty of information online about it.